# char* escape "\" are being lost in libcurl's POSTFIELD

Tags: c++, libcurl, put

I have two examples of using POSTFIELDS - the first works fine and the second does not

I am not sure if this is down to libcurl or the compiler removing the escape "\" from the character 'send'.

if I make 'send' an std::string rather that a char* then I get a bad request error saying "unexpected token in Json"

this is a comparison of how I am using POSTFIELDS

```
char* send;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"var\":\"info\"}");
```

and

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, send);
```

I get a 500 error that shows as

```
Unhandled error in PUT /random/page 500 AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The data argument must be an object
```

There is also problem with the output from libcurl

```
> PUT /random/page HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
charsets: utf-8
Content-Length: 364

* upload completely sent off: 364 out of 364 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2019 11:30:55 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 62
```

The content length at the bottom does not match the request

Comment: What about using [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)?

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, send);` -- Where do you initialize the `send` pointer?

Comment: I pass 'send' to the function as a string (for the sake of concatenate) then convert to char. If I print 'send' as a char and then copy and paste the output into the first example then everything works the way that is is supposed to.

Comment: When you `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, `curl_easy_setopt` does not copy the argument, so you need to make sure that the pointer stays valid until you're done. You can use `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` instead, but that has some other caveats. Read the documentation thoroughly.

Comment: `std::string send = "{\"var\":\"info\"}"; curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, send.c_str());` Just make sure `send` stays in scope, and is not modified, until `curl_easy_perform()` is done.